# Why am I getting a segmentation fault from scanf loop?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

The segmentation fault error disappears after commenting out the scanf loop. Why is that loop giving me a segmentation fault?

```c
char** nameArray =  malloc(numNames * sizeof(char *)); 

for(i =0; i< 10; i++) { 
  nameArray[i] = malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
}

for (i = 0; i< numNames; i++) { 
  scanf("%s", &nameArray[i]);
}

for (i =0; i<numNames; i++) { 
  free(nameArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: How long is the string being scanned? Try to malloc large array to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Scan to `nameArray[i]`, not to `&nameArray[i]`. Also use `"%24s"` as your format string and check the return value of `scanf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to change

```
for(i =0; i< 10; i++) {
```

to

```
for(i =0; i< numNames; i++) {
```

as you need to create enough entries.

Also you need to change this line

```
scanf("%s", &nameArray[i]);
```

to

```
scanf("%s", nameArray[i]);
```

as `nameArray[i]` is a character pointer as required.

Also it would be better to use

```
scanf("%24s", nameArray[i]);
```

as this would prevent buffer overrun. Also it would be a good idea to check the return value of scant

Answer (score 2):

It is because `nameArray[i]` is already a pointer, obtained from `malloc`, so you only need to pass that pointer to `scanf`, using

```
scanf("%s", nameArray[i]);
```

without the `&`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to take care of allocation ;
in your case you allocate only 10 namearray elements

you have to make allocation for all variables you will scanf :
change 10 with numNames

```
for(i =0; i< numNames; i++) { 
  nameArray[i] = malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
}
```

and the & sign is used with normale charls in pointer case don't use it ;

```
scanf("%s",nameArray[i]);
```